# How to resolve 'The system cannot find the path specified.' issue in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I want to run a batch file which present in this folder

> 'D:\Maximo Workspace\Maximo-7.6-CD\tools\maximo>'

I am trying to run a batch command from this like

> 'D:\Maximo Workspace\Maximo-7.6-CD\tools\maximo>updatedb.bat'

but i am getting error stating that **'The system cannot find the path specified.'**

[image: Command prompt screenshot]

I am running as a window administrator too, i have tried few things which i have read from other stack overflow questions like running this batch file from SysWOW64 too but still it is giving same issue.

Can any body help me with this why it is happening as batch file is there in the folder.

**update.db content**

```
@ECHO OFF

REM
REM DO NO EDIT THIS FILE
REM AUTO Generated from updatedb.xml
REM
REM Script: updatedb
REM Converted updatedb.bat file.
REM
REM To get help, use --help
REM

SETLOCAL

set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
set SCRIPT_NAME=updatedb.xml
set MAXIMO_SCRIPT_CP=%SCRIPT_DIR%\internal

if "%MAXIMO_JAVA%"=="" set MAXIMO_JAVA=%SCRIPT_DIR%\..\java\jre\bin\java.exe

@"%MAXIMO_JAVA%" -cp "%MAXIMO_SCRIPT_CP%" MaximoScript "%SCRIPT_DIR%%SCRIPT_NAME%" %*

exit /B %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Did you check whether the batch file exists at this folder? Also check for the exact spelling of the batch file.

Comment: yes, updatedb.bat is there, also I am using the tab at command location to find this update.db. If it is not there it will not show at very first place.

Comment: We need to see the contents of `updatedb.bat`. The batch appears to be running and it's an instruction within the batch that is generating the message.

Comment: added the contents of updated.db, there is no such line as such.

Comment: Does `D:\Maximo Workspace\Maximo-7.6-CD\tools\maximo\..\java\jre\bin\java.exe` exist? i.e. `D:\Maximo Workspace\Maximo-7.6-CD\tools\java\jre\bin\java.exe`, after resolving the ".." in the path.

Comment: It is not there, I have added **java\jre\bin\java.exe** and it worked perfectly, not sure why this folder gets deleted as previously the same folder is there.
But any way thanks @eryksun and others for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Resolved**

I have opened the updatedb.bat file and found that the jre is required at this location

like this    `D:\Maximo Workspace\Maximo-7.6-CD\tools\java\jre\bin\java.exe` , same has been added as required, and it worked smoothly.